# Is language bin(n)bin(2^(k+1) n + 1)^R context-free

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, context-free

I have a problem with this exercise. For language $$L_1 = \{ w \in \{0, 1\}^* : \exists k \in \mathbb N  \ w = \text{bin}(n)(\text{bin}(2^{k+1}n + 1))^R  \},$$ where $\cdot^R$ reverses a string and $\text{bin}(n)$ is the representation of $n$ in base 2. I need to determine if this language is regular, context-free or not and prove. I thought I could use the complement of $L_1$, but I can't get any intuition in this approach.

Comment: What is $n$? Any natural number?

Comment: @JohnL. yes, n is in natural numbers

Comment: Isn't bin(2^k n) = bin(n) 0^k ?

Comment: @HendrikJan so it's just adding another 0?

Comment: @bluerabbit Not just one, but k+1 zeroes, it seems. also don't forget its actually bin(2^{k+1} n + 1).